# How to insert a merge field custom text field in sales force?

Tags: custom-field

I have an existing custom field with the data type text  and its contain some default value  like 'Dear sir/madam,'

Here my question is ...can I insert a merge field (salutation) to pass dynamic values here.... from the same object.

Is it possible?

Comment: You can use a formula field to construct a value from a template like this, if that's what you mean. You can't use Text fields as templates without some custom Apex, and I wouldn't recommend that approach in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As David Reed suggested,

The easiest approach is to merge a formula field. Then use that custom field as the merge:

{!Object.Dynamic_Salutation__c}

If you are using a contact for the email template they already have a salutation field on the record.

{!Contact.Salutation}